# Question about Properties of Exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm just doing some assignments and I was a little confused by this, could someone explain why the second equation is not equal like the first one? From what I've learned, if you take the inverse you switch the exponential sign (positive to neg for example)
$$\frac{3^{1}} {1^{}} = \frac{1^{}} {3^{-1}}$$
$$\frac{1^{1}} {3^{}} ≠ \frac{3^{}} {1^{-1}}$$

Comment: since in the second equation you have $\frac{1}{3}$ on the left hand side and you have $3$ on the right hand side.

Comment: Why has this question been down-voted?  It is a valid question. It contains OPs thoughts and effort. It includes proper formatting using Mathjax. This is one of the few examples where a new user actually posts a good question - and in return gets negative feedback.

Answer (score 1):

What is true is $$\left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^{-1} = \frac{b}{a}$$

For the first equation.

$$\frac{1}{3^{-1}}=\frac{1^{-1}}{3^{-1}}=\left( \frac13\right)^{-1}=\frac{3}{1}$$

but for the second equation

$$\frac{3}{1^{-1}} \neq \left(\frac31 \right)^{-1}$$